# How to check if an Array contains a particular word in a String and get it?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have a `String[]` and an input `String`:

```
String[] ArrayEx = new String[1];
String textInput = "a whole bunch of words"
```

What I want to do is check if the `String` contains a word present in the `Array`, like this.

Ex: `textInput = "for example"` and `ArrayEx[0] = "example"`

I know about this method:

```
Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourValue)
```

but it checks the full `String` right? How do I check if the `String` contains a particular **word** present in the Array. Even if it is from an `ArrayList` I have no problem.

Also if yes, can I get that word from the `String[]`? i.e., in the above case get the `String` "example".

**EDIT:**

```
public void searchNearestPlace(String v2txt)
{
    Log.e("TAG", "Started");
    v2txt = v2txt.toLowerCase();
    String[] places = {"accounting, airport, amusement_park, aquarium, art_gallery, atm, bakery, bank, bar, beauty_salon, bicycle_store, book_store, bowling_alley, bus_station, cafe, campground, car_dealer, car_rental, car_repair, car_wash, casino, cemetery, church, city_hall, clothing_store, convenience_store, courthouse, dentist, department_store, doctor, electrician, electronics_store, embassy, establishment, finance, fire_station, florist, food, funeral_home, furniture_store, gas_station, general_contractor, grocery_or_supermarket, gym, hair_care, hardware_store, health, hindu_temple, home_goods_store, hospital, insurance_agency, jewelry_store, laundry, lawyer, library, liquor_store, local_government_office, locksmith, lodging, meal_delivery, meal_takeaway, mosque, movie_rental, movie_theater, moving_company, museum, night_club, painter, park, parking, pet_store, pharmacy, physiotherapist, place_of_worship, plumber, police, post_office, real_estate_agency, restaurant, roofing_contractor, rv_park, school, shoe_store, shopping_mall, spa, stadium, storage, store, subway_station, synagogue, taxi_stand, train_station, travel_agency, university, veterinary_care, zoo"};
    int index;
    for(int i = 0; i<= places.length - 1; i++)
    {
        Log.e("TAG","for");
        if(v2txt.contains(places[i]))
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "sensed?!");
            index = i;
    }
}
```

Say `v2txt` was `"awesome airport"` the sensed Log never does appear even though all other logs indicate it working

**Edit2:**

I am so embarrassed that I made such a dunder head mistake. My array is declared wrongly. There should be a `"` before every `,`. I am such a big idiot!
Sorry will change it and let you know.

Comment: Guys why the down votes. Is there something wrong. Please do let me know also.

Comment: Start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Is the array of one word strings only, or can the array entries have full sentences as well?

Comment: Array one or 2 words. And String sentences

Comment: And you want to know if the sentence contains any of the words from the array, or just the (1 or 2 word) phrases from the array?

Comment: If the array[0] is "hello world", would the sentence "hello dude" be a match?

Comment: No. But if that is the only way ok.

Comment: I am sorry all of them were correct but since I could give only one correct I gave it to the guy who first answered. Sorry. But I gave everyone one up vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it has nothing to do with android

Second the solution

```
boolean flag = false;
String textInput = "for example";
int index = 0;
String[] yourArray = {"ak", "example"};
for (int i = 0; i <= yourArray.length - 1; i++) {

    if (textInput.contains(yourArray[i])) {
        flag = true;
        index = i;

    }
}
if (flag) 
   System.out.println("found at index " + index);
else 
   System.out.println("not found ");
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/f3Qp5h)

**EDIT** :

Change your array to

```
String[] places = {"accounting", "airport", "amusement_park" };
```

and so on with other values with your array declaration it has one index.

Comment: But doesn't this check the full String?

Comment: And 2 sorry this was for an android project but you are right this code does not relate to android. I'll remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but still won't it check the full String instead of one word by one.

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE this code take the string at each index of array and finds if it is a substring of `textInput` is that what you wanted? added a demo also

Comment: I am trying all the solution's please give me some time

Comment: I don't understand the logic is perfect yet it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I already saw that. As in my question edit. I am so embarrassed. Anyway edited it with notepad and it's done. Am running it on my device now.

Comment: It worked. I am sorry all of them were correct but since I could give only one correct I gave it to the guy who first answered. Sorry. But I gave everyone one up vote.

Answer (score 1):

you can split your string and get array of words

```
txArray = textInput.split(" ");
```

then for each element in txArray check if

```
Arrays.asList(ArrayEx).contains(txArray[i])
```

Comment: How would I get them into an array. And how would I get the word in the array.

Comment: `txArray = textInput.split(" ");` creates array of words

Comment: It works but it's kinda complex. Like I int i will be the new arrays lenght or it gives a npe. But

Comment: I am sorry all of them were correct but since I could give only one correct I gave it to the guy who first answered. Sorry. But I gave everyone one up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

Sting text2check = "Your Name":

```
for(int t = 0; t < array.length; t++)
{
if (text2check.equals(array[t])
// Process it Here
break;
}
```

Comment: There is no to String available on an array

Comment: I will edit my answer, i was trying to say the return value of array is string because you to store string in it. Alternatively use String.valueof(array[t]) if it is not String already.

Comment: Ok understood. No need of to String and it's working now.

Comment: I am sorry all of them were correct but since I could give only one correct I gave it to the guy who first answered. Sorry. But I gave everyone one up vote.

Comment: Also for my purpose `.equals` should probably be `.contains`

Answer (score 1):

This will take an String array, and search through all the strings looking for a specific char sequence found in a string. Also, native Android apps are programmed in the Java language. You might find it beneficial to read up more on [Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
String [] stringArray = new String[5];
//populate your array
String inputText = "abc";
for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    if(inputText.contains(stringArray[i]){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry all of them were correct but since I could give only one correct I gave it to the guy who first answered. Sorry. But I gave everyone one up vote.

Comment: Also for my purpose `stringArray[i].contains(inputText)` should probably be `inputText.contains(stringArray[i])`

Comment: Yes, I see that upon re reading the question. I thought you wanted the answer the other way around. My mistake

Comment: Hey no problem. It was almost correct want it and also you took the effort to help others right? No problem

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
txArray = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splitStr = txArray.split(" ");
int i=0;
while(splitStr[i]){
if(Arrays.asList(ArrayEx).contains(txArray[i])){
System.out.println("FOUND");
}
i++;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry all of them were correct but since I could give only one correct I gave it to the guy who first answered. Sorry. But I gave everyone one up vote and BTW it's a duplicate. Still no problem 

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java - Regular Expressions.

> A regular expression is a special sequence of characters that helps you match or find other strings or sets of strings, using a specialized syntax held in a pattern. They can be used to search, edit, or manipulate text and data.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String textInput = "for example";
        String[] arrayEx = new String[1];
        arrayEx[0] = "example";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(arrayEx[0]);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(textInput);
        boolean matchedFoundStatus = false;
        while (m.find()) {
            matchedFoundStatus = true;
        }
        System.out.println("matchedFoundStatus:" + matchedFoundStatus);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sorry all of them were correct but since I could give only one correct I gave it to the guy who first answered. Sorry. But I gave everyone one up vote.

Answer (score 1):

*"How do I check if the String contains a particular word present in the Array?"* is the same thing as *Is there an element in the array, for which the input string contains this element*

**Java 8**

```
String[] words = { "example", "hello world" };
String input = "a whole bunch of words";

Arrays.stream(words).anyMatch(input::contains);
```

(The matching words can also be extracted, if needed:)

```
Arrays.stream(words)
      .filter(input::contains)
      .toArray();
```

If you are stuck with Java 7, you will have to re-implement "anyMatch" and "filter" yourself:

**Java 7**

```
boolean anyMatch(String[] words, String input) {
    for(String s : words)
        if(input.contains(s))
            return true;
    return false;
}

List<String> filter(String[] words, String input) {
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s : words)
        if(input.contains(s))
            matches.add(s);
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's answered now. I am sorry all of them were correct but since I could give only one correct I gave it to the guy who first answered. Sorry. But I gave everyone one up vote.

Comment: Don't be sorry :) Just select the answer that helped you, and good luck with your program!

Comment: Ok thanks. Wish I could mark multiple answers as correct though.

Comment: All upvoted answers will be "correct" in some sense, the "selected" answer is just so that people with the same problem as you can find "any solution" at a glance.

Comment: Ya but still for you guys 15 points out right. I feel bad I can't give you them to you guys even after all the effort you guys put into it.